# Instagram ?__a=1 endopoint doesn't work through cURL

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I used to fetch latest public profile images from Instagram through the **?__a=1** endpoint

```
example: https://www.instagram.com/ferrari/?__a=1
```

However currently I'm getting no JSON. Just a blank HTML code having this title: "Login • Instagram".

Here's my cURL code:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Does Instagram require specific cURL parameters actually?

Comment: They disabled these legacy APIs today, see https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So why we are still able to reach that URL and also gather that JSON through javascript..? Sounds like an instagram block against server calls